# Spring-data-rest POST link throws Null-Pointer Exception

Tags: spring, rest, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I have an entity called `StockLevel` and another one called `Version` and they are in a relationship like this:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "version", nullable = false, referencedColumnName = "pk")
private VersionModel version;
```

Now I want to create a new `StockLevel` via Spring-Data-REST so I issue the following POST request to http://somedomain.com:8111/storefront/rest/stock_level/

```
{
   "uid" : "mynewuidForStockLevel",
   "version" : 
   {
      "rel" : "version",
      "href":"http://localhost:8111/storefront/rest/version/3378719354003680"
   }
}
```

Here is my `Version` model:

```
@Cacheable 
@Entity(name = VersionModel.NAME) 
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE) 
@Table(name = VersionModel.NAME, 
       uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "pk" }) }, 
       indexes = { @Index(columnList = "id")}) 
public class VersionModel extends AbstractEntityModel {
    public static final String NAME = "version";
}
```

however I get a Null-pointer exception in Fasterxml Jackson:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3023)
at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:595)
at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:857)
at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.json.PersistentEntityJackson2Module$UriStringDeserializer.deserialize(PersistentEntityJackson2Module.java:359)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:525)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:99)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:242)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `"version": "http://localhost:8111/storefront/rest/version/3378719354003680"`?

Comment: How does your VersionModel entity look like?

Comment: Here's the VersionModel:

Comment: @Cacheable
    @Entity(name = VersionModel.NAME)
    @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
    @Table(name = VersionModel.NAME, uniqueConstraints = {      @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "pk" }) }, indexes = {      @Index(columnList = "id")})
    public class VersionModel extends AbstractEntityModel {
         public static final String NAME = "version";
    }

Comment: This website is such a SHIT!!!!! I cannot post code in the reply - I added 4 spaces and it still doesn't show as code.

Comment: @beerbajay It's a relation, not a `String` property!

Comment: @PetarTahchiev - the best thing to do here would be to update the main question with the new code, and comment about it here. That also makes the Question/Answer format of the website easier to read for future users, and prevents the site from turning into a forum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to create an association to the related resource directly when creating a resource, the value submitted for the relation has to be a URI directly, not an object of some sorts. The sample you showed will work if you adapt it like this:

```
{ "uid" : "mynewuidForStockLevel",
  "version" : "http://localhost:8111/storefront/rest/version/3378719354003680" }
```

Comment: It worked (some more characters to make it more than 8 so that this stupid website will accept my comment)